# XML SDK recalculate values

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an excel file and I have a piece of code that updates some cells with a formula.

Before saving the file I set these two boolean properties:

```
spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
// Save the worksheet.
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
```

After saving the file, I open it again using the Open XML SDK, but I'm still getting the old values. When I open the excel file using Excel and I save it, then I can see the new values.

Do you know how I can make the values recalculate? If I save the file, I was expecting that if I open it, the values should be recalculated.

Thanks.Jose.

Answer (score 1):

If you have cached values then those values will be used and the values will not be recalculated. Try flushing the cached values like in this snippet:

```
public static void FlushCachedValues(SpreadsheetDocument doc)
{
   doc.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts
      .SelectMany(part => part.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>())
      .SelectMany(data => data.Elements<Row>())
      .SelectMany(row => row.Elements<Cell>())
      .Where(cell => cell.CellFormula != null && cell.CellValue != null)
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(cell => cell.CellValue.Remove());
 }
```

Just make sure you call this method before you save the document.

Comment: Its not working as expected. Al the CellValues becoming blank.

Comment: It's working for me - are you saying the CellValues are showing as blank in Excel? Or showing as blank in the file you saved? They will only be recalculated once you load the workbook in Excel.